# Drupal - How to update a CCK NodeReference field programmatically?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, cck

I'm trying to create a node (B type) & assign it to a A type node's CCK nodereference field using node_save() method.

```
$node_type_A = node_load($some_nid);
$node_type_A->field_type_B_node_ref[]['nid'] = $node_type_B_nid;

$node_type_A = node_submit($node_type_A);
node_save($node_type_A);
```

As the result, a new B type node will be created, but no reference will be assigned to the A type node. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GApple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723574/drupal-how-to-update-a-cck-nodereference-field-programmatically/2724506#2724506) is right, the format is correct, but there are couple of things that you might want to care about.

**Delta Value**
First you need to know the *delta* value of the latest node reference attached to `$node_type_A`, the *delta* is actually a partial index, when combined with `vid` field of the `$node_type_A`, they become the index for node reference table in the database. In other words, its a count for `$node_type_B` which are referenced in `$node_type_A`, ok?

[GApple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723574/drupal-how-to-update-a-cck-nodereference-field-programmatically/2724506#2724506) is right again, you have to exactly say where to add the new reference. When you got that *delta* value you can exactly say where to append *(delta+1)* the new reference. Here it is:

```
function get_current_delta($node_vid){
    return db_result(db_query("SELECT delta FROM {content_field_type_A_node_ref}
                               WHERE vid = '%d'
                               ORDER BY delta DESC
                               LIMIT 1", $node_vid));
}
```

**Adding the new reference**
We got *delta*! so we can attach the new `$node_type_B` node to our `$node_type_A` node:

```
// Loading type_A node.
$node_type_A = node_load($some_nid);

// Getting current delta value.
$current_delta = get_current_delta($node_type_A->vid);

// "Appending" a node reference based on delta. 
$node_type_A->field_type_B_node_ref += array($current_delta + 1 => array('nid' => $node_type_B_nid));
```

**Resaving the updated node**
Optionally call `node_submit()` to populate some essential fields in the node object and save it by utilizing `node_save()`. After all, you need to call [`content_insert()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/function/content_insert/6) to make the node completely saved asidelong with its CCK fields:

```
// Resaving the updated node.
$node_type_A = node_submit($node_type_A);
node_save($node_type_A);
content_insert($node_type_A);
```

**Flushing the content cache**
Probably the most important part, this was killin' me for couple of days. CCK has a cache table in the database called `cache_content` *(take a look at its structure)*, after resaving the updated node, you will notice that nothing has changed in the `$node_type_A` theme output even though that the tables are updated. We have to remove a record from that content cache table, this will force Drupal to show the latest snapshot of the data. You can define the following as a function:

```
db_query("DELETE FROM {cache_content} WHERE cid = '%s'", 'content:' . $node_type_A->nid . ':' . $node_type_A->vid);
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: ...and this is why I hate programming with the drupal API. That solution is ridiculous. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 4):

I just checked one of my own modules that does something similar for the object format, and  `$node_type_A->field_type_B_node_ref[]['nid']` should be correct.

One thing to check for is that when you load the node, CCK may pre-populate the node reference array with an empty value.  If you have configured the field to only allow one value, by using the array append operator (`field_type_B_node_ref[]`) it will create a second entry that will be ignored (`field_type_B_node_ref[1]`), instead of overwriting the existing value (`field_type_B_node_ref[0]`).  Try explicitly specifying the array key if possible.

Comment: I've just checked that & it was set to `unlimit`, Also I tried to specify the exact index value of the array, still nothing :(

Answer (score 3):

Great post, but one correction: don't flush cache entries by manually querying the DB. In the event someone is using memcache or any other external cache it's going to fail.

[cache_clear_all()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/6) is your friend for clearing.

Suggested code, direct from the CCK module:

```
cache_clear_all('content:'. $node_type_A->nid .':'. $node_type_A->vid, content_cache_tablename());
```

Answer (score 0):

I show CCK storing node references as `$node->field_node_reference[0]['items'][0]['nid']`, not  `$node->field_node_reference[0]['nid']`. Have you tried mimicking that?

Comment: gonna try that, and I'll post back the results.

Comment: Hmm. I don't see anything wrong with the code, then. Are you sure `$node_type_B_nid` is properly populated?

Comment: yes, I'm sure. there's nothing buggy about that `$node_type_B_nid`. Additionally I used to use `$node->field_node_ref[0..n]['nid']` format while CREATING nodes & it works, but it failing now, on update, thank you anyways.

Comment: are you using that code on a nodeapi hook? notice there are different $op for creating the node and editing it. check http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_nodeapi/6 for more info.

Comment: content cache was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

"Flushing the content cache" This works for me, especially if you get a data from node_load()

Comment: you can add a comment on an answer instead of answering a comment ^^